# Source files for Laravel Hash::make

Tags: php, laravel, hash, password-protection

I cant find the source files for Laravels "Hash:make();" function.

I am about to put an application online that I built from scratch using no framework. But first I want to change the way my application Hash passwords using Laravels function.

So that I later can implement that database used with the old application to a new one built with Laravel.

So now im just worried that I cant hash / unHash the passwords in the database once I implement it with the Laravel app. Thats why I want to use Laravels Hash from start so I dont run in to problem later

Comment: Not sure you can "un-Hash" data as such. It will do a hash comparison to see if the hash stored matches what has been entered.

Comment: Sorry asked my question the wrong way. I ment hash comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php`

```
/**
 * Hash the given value.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */
public function make($value, array $options = array())
{
    $cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;

    $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));

    if ($hash === false)
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Bcrypt hashing not supported.");
    }

    return $hash;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is the code for the hash comparison located there aswell? Cant check my self right now, so just curious.

Comment: You can check the public API by going to http://laravel.com/api/4.2/ and typing 'BcryptHasher'